# How many four digit numbers can be formed from 0-9?

Tags: probability

How many four digit numbers can be formed from 0-9 if:

- repetitions are allowed

  9000 ways
- the number is less than 5000 and no repetitions are allowed

  1680 1344 1008 360
- no repetitions are allowed

  5040 4536 3024 2688
- the number ends in 5 and repetition is allowed

  648 729 5832 6561

Comment: Can it start with a zero?  Is this home work and what have you tried.

Comment: @WarrenHill it can't start with zero or it will not be a four digit number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Obviously [1000 - 9999] - 9000 numbers (if numbers like 0xxx accepted then 10^4 = 10000)
2)First digit must be [1-4] so it 4 * (10!/(10 - 3)!) = 4 * (10 * 9 * 8) = 2880, in case of [0-4] = 3600  
3) 10! / (10 - 4)! = 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 = 5040 in general case, if can not start with zeros we exclude [0-999] - (10!/ (10 - 4) !) - (10! / (10 - 3)! ) =  4320
4) again, you have numbers like [xyz5] so if x allows zeros: 10^3 = 1000, else 9 * 10 * 10 = 900.
So your answers are: 9000, 2880, 4320 and 900 if you can not start your number with 0.